# Place a CircularProgressIndicator inside RaisedButton mantaining size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place a `CircularProgressIndicator` inside a `RaisedButton`, but when I do it, the `CircularProgressIndicator` doesn't fit the button and sticks out of it.

I want to shrink the `CircularProgressIndicator`, so that it fits inside the `RaisedButton`, I know I can do it using a `SizedBox` but I want it to be automatic, not that I give it the size that I want. I tried `FittedBox` but all its options make no difference at all.

this is my button's code:

```dart
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => print('hi'),
    shape: StadiumBorder(),
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[       
      Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, top: 6, bottom: 6),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            strokeWidth: 2,
          ),
        ),        
        Text('Loading'),
      ],
    ),
),
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

When I Add `Padding` it grows the button:

[image]

Are there any ways to achieve this automatically?

---

EDIT:

Just to make it clear, the end effect that I want is this:

Before and after the user presses the button:

[image] [image]

I want the height to stay the same, automatically, without magic values inside a `SizedBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `CircularProgressIndicator` source code, I can find there's a hardcoded minimum size of 36.0 height/width, so there's no way of getting smaller than that automatically.

Comment: While you're obviously sort of correct, it would be helpful I think if you linked/mentioned your proposal that's on GitHub (since it's more of a complete technical answer/explanation to this question): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46803
...and perhaps while you're at it, mark your own answer as the answer (since that can be changed later if your proposal gains traction).

Comment: The result you want is actually possible using `SizedBox` Checkout my answer for info.

Answer (score 8):

This is totally possible. You wrap the `CircularProgressIndicator` inside a `SizedBox` to constrain it to that size. Also using `MainAxisSize.Min` in the `Row` prevents the button from trying to expand to infinite size.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)),
        child: isLoading
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text("Loading"),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        strokeWidth: 3,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : Text("Not Loading"))
```

This gives you the following
[image: Blue button with circular progress indicator]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. CircularProgressIndicator inside SizedBox works. Tested in Flutter 2.2.3

Comment: yes, just works!! flutter version 2.5 at the time of testing.

Comment: Not sure if he updated the question afterwards but they stated they didn't want to add some specific ("magic") values inside of a `SizedBox`

Comment: It was updated after my answer. This could always be abstracted into a component so those "magic" values are kept in one place. Until the proposal mentioned under the Author's answer is implemented I think this is the best solution to achieve what is needed

Answer (score 1):

I re-created your case and was able to see the `CircularProgressIndicator` properly inside the `RaisedButton` maintaining it's size.

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Progress Button',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Progress Button'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => print('hi'),
              shape: StadiumBorder(),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, top: 6, bottom: 6),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      strokeWidth: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('Loading'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output (both platforms):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then it's probably related to the rest of my widget tree, let me check then where the problem arises

Comment: I just tested your code, I can clearly see that when the the `CircularProgressIndicator` is removed the button shrinks its height, so no, the size is not maintained when a `CircularProgressIndicator` is inside it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to make space between your widgets in `Row`.

You can wrap your `Row` widget to a `Padding` widget to make padding for whole content in your button as well.

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         children: <Widget>[       
           CircularProgressIndicator(
               backgroundColor: Colors.white,
               strokeWidth: 2,
           ),        
           Text('Loading'),
         ],
     ), 
)
```

Comment: Can't see how this will change anything, as in the end the child of the button will be bigger.